# database not stored on docker-image with shinyproxy

Tags: r, sqlite, docker, shinyproxy

I have developed a solution and decided to use shinyproxy.

I have the following problem:

A user needs to capture data on the solution, which must be stored and updated on the database for all users accessing the solution, I used SQLite and with R for this.

Now when I log in and capture data, it saves, but when i log in with a different user I dont get to find the captured data.

The problem is that saving data doesnt seem to be saving on the docker image, why is this and how can I go about remedying it?

For problem testing purposes:

Solution link: https://xxasdfqexx.com

Data Capturer user:

username: xxxxx

password: Fxxxx

Admin user:

username: inxxx

password: prupxxxxx

Testing:

Inside the solution, if you go to the data management tab, data entry and then right click on an table and insert a new row, click save changes, it must safe new changes to the docker image but its only temporarily doing so, the other user cant see the changes made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The SQLite DB is stored within the running *container*, not the image. It is therefore lost when the container is shut down. And shinyproxy starts a new container for every user. The general solution with docker is to use an [external volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) that is mounted into the running container and use that file/directory to store persistent data. Together with shinyproxy, you have to use `docker-volumes`, c.f. 
https://www.shinyproxy.io/configuration/#apps.

Putting this together you can use in the shinyproxy config something like:

```
apps:
  - name: ...
    docker-cmd: ...
    docker-image: ...
    docker-volumes: /some/local/path/:/mnt/persistent
```

And in the shiny app something like:

```
dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "/mnt/persistent/my-db.sqlite")
```

Comment: I have attempted to do the above but I got very lost as no changes are not made still. Do you have a tutorial perhaps you can direct me to?, I am fairly new to Docker and shinyproxy

Comment: @nybre See the updated answer for a more explicit solution. I don't know of any how-to for shinyproxy. The "external volume" link already explains how volumes are used to persist data. There might be other how-tos, but I am not aware of them.

Comment: This actually worked, thanks, what I was missing was the r shiny code, directory were misaligned